# Resize image before upload php

Tags: php

I want to resize an image before it is uploaded.

```
 if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        if (isset($_FILES['file']['error'])) {
            foreach ($_FILES['file']['error'] as $uploadedFileKey => $uploadedFileError) {
                if ($uploadedFileError === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
                    $errors[] = 'You did not provide any files.';
                } elseif ($uploadedFileError === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                    $uploadedFileName = basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$uploadedFileKey]);

                    if ($_FILES['file']['size'][$uploadedFileKey] <= UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
                        $uploadedFileType = $_FILES['file']['type'][$uploadedFileKey];
                        $uploadedFileTempName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$uploadedFileKey];

                        $uploadedFilePath = rtrim(UPLOAD_DIR, '/') . '/' . $uploadedFileName;

                        if (in_array($uploadedFileType, $allowedMimeTypes)) {
                            if (!move_uploaded_file($uploadedFileTempName, $uploadedFilePath)) {
                                $errors[] = 'The file "' . $uploadedFileName . '" could not be uploaded.';
                            } else {
                                $filenamesToSave[] = $uploadedFilePath;

                            }
                        } else {
                            $errors[] = 'The extension of the file "' . $uploadedFileName . '" is not valid. Allowed extensions: JPG, JPEG, PNG, or GIF.';
                        }
                    } else {
                        $errors[] = '<div style="margin-top:50px;">The size of the file "' . $uploadedFileName . '" - ERROR</div>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: PHP lives on the server, so it can't do anything before the data is uploaded. You probably want JavaScript.

Comment: @Sammitch Probably yes, can you please show how to do that or how to upload fast large images?

Comment: There are many JS libraries to do that resizing. Ex: https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/. But you have to do more than PHP work